# Bootstrap Modal not responsive for mobile devices

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal

I am designing a login form which is almost done. Issue I am facing is that the (bootstrap)modal which I am using is not responsive for mobile devices. 
I have included bootstrap.min.css file. Please Help!

```html
<section class="at-login-form">
  <!-- MODAL LOGIN -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="at-login" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span></button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body"> 
          <form name = "logform" method = "POST" id = "myform1" onsubmit = "return validateForm()">
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="email" class="form-control-form " id="exampleInputEmaillog" name = "ename" placeholder="Email">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="password" class="form-control-form " id="exampleInputPasswordpas" name = "pass" placeholder="Password">
            </div>
            <div class="row"> 
              <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="checkbox">
                  <label>
                    <input type="checkbox"> Remember me
                  </label>
                </div> 
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-2"> 
                <p class="frgt-pswd" data-toggle="modal" data-dismiss="modal"  data-target="#at-reset-pswd">
                  Forgot Password ?
                </p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <input type="submit" class="btn-lgin" value = "Sign In">
          </form>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <div class="row"> 
            <div class="col-md-6">
              <p class="ta-l">Don't have an account ? </p>
            </div> 
            <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-2"> 
              <button class="btn-gst"  data-toggle="modal"  data-dismiss="modal" data-target="#at-signup" >
                Sign Up
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "not responsive"? Is it that the form is not responding to the user input or it's not scaling to fit the size of the viewport?

Comment: do you have the bootstrap css linked in the head and the js before the body close tag?

Comment: I use the bootstrap modal myself, it is indeed not responsive. You need to make it responsive yourself using `css media queries`

Comment: @gmferland It is not scaling to fit the size of viewport.

Comment: @ChintanSavla see my answer

Answer (score 2):

Bootstrap is not just a responsive layout, but it allows you to be very specific about how you want your layout to look at different viewport sizes. This means for a lot of classes, you choose a specific minimum viewport width that you want the element to display at. Below that minimum, the element will take up a full 12 columns. The exact pixel widths for viewport sizes are defined in the [Media Queries section of the documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#grid-media-queries), but it roughly breaks down to `xs` for phones, `sm` for tablets, `md` for small laptops, and `lg` for larger laptops and desktops.

For example, `col-md-6` means "display as 6 columns when the viewport is medium or larger, and display as 12 columns when the viewport is smaller than medium." You're allowed to combine multiple classes in this way to target multiple viewport widths. For example, `col-sm-8 col-md-6 col-lg-4` will display as 12 columns for `xs`, 8 for `sm`, 6 for `md`, and 4 for `lg`.

So looking at your code, you only use `col-md-*` classes (`col-md-6`, `col-md-offset-2`), so your layout is only kicking in at the medium viewport width. If you want your layout to be the same for all viewport sizes, you want to use `col-xs-*` classes instead. If you want to have slightly different looks for mobile and desktop, use a `col-xs-*` and a `col-md-*` class on all your `div`s. Just beware that dividing your layout up too much on `xs` devices can lead to columns that are too small for their content, which will look bad.

Answer (score 1):

For modal backdrop issue.  You can add this css.

```
.modal-backdrop{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Sometime modal backdrop overlay not fit on mobile view.

Answer (score 0):

As @gmferland mentioned, this is a limitation of Bootstrap modals.

You may want to use my library to overcome it: https://github.com/keaukraine/bootstrap-fs-modal

Also available for Bootstrap 4: https://github.com/keaukraine/bootstrap4-fs-modal